# SSIS TargetServerVersion causes null rows in script component

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

When I set the TargetServerVersion = SqlServer2012 in my SSIS project, my script component throws a null object exception.

I am importing about 140,000 records from a CSV file. To confirm I do get records, I removed my script component step and ran the flow with no issues.

[image]

I then added back in the Script Component (which has worked fine with this very data file) and I get the null exception.

When I debug the script and check the value of the Row property it says the following:

```
?Row
{Input0Buffer}
    Buffer: {Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer}
    BufferColumnIndexes: {int[2]}
    MembershipPlanName: 'Row.MembershipPlanName' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
    MembershipPlanName_IsNull: 'Row.MembershipPlanName_IsNull' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
```

The script then fails when the rest of the lines try to reference Row. When I change the TargetServerVersion back to 2016 or 2014, the package works fine.

During debegging I also looked at BufferWrapper.cs and there seems to be some data in there

```
?Buffer
{Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer}
    ColumnCount: 2
    ColumnInfo: 0x0000000000000000
    CurrentRow: 0
    EndOfRowset: false
    Mode: Input
    RowCount: 9936
    RowSize: 260145280
    RowStarts: 0x000000000f82b700
```

Answer (score 1):

Out of frustration I installed SSDT for VS2012.  For some reason, that made everything work fine in VS2015. Not sure why it worked, but posting this if anyone has a similar issue.